# Debian 10 apache2 virtual hosts for subdomain

Tags: debian, apache-virtualhost, domain

I have `Debian 10` and `apache2` and in `virtual hosts` configuration for subdomain. Configuration for main domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName system.com
    ServerAlias system.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/system.com
    
    <Directory /var/www/system.com>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
</VirtualHost>
```

For my subdomain configuration in virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.system.com
    ServerAlias api.system.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/api.system.com
    
    <Directory /var/www/api.system.com>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
#       Order Allow,Deny
#       Allow from All
    </Directory>

    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And now, when I type system.com in my browser, it shows index.html from system.com directory. When I type api.system.com it shows index.html from api.system.com folder.

Output for command: `sudo apache2ctl -S`:

```
my@server088331:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server api.system.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/api.system.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost api.system.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/api.system.conf:1)
                 alias api.system.com
         port 80 namevhost phpmyadmin.system.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:1)
                 alias phpmyadmin.system.com
         port 80 namevhost system.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/system.conf:1)
                 alias system.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Everything looks ok, but the issue is with subdomain. When I type api.system.com I get content of index.html from api.system.com directory. But when I type for example api55.system.com I get index.html from api.system.com either. The same result is for api41.system.com etc. Despite these domains don't exists and don't exist configuration in virtual hosts for these domains

How to configure virtual hosts to allow get index.html only for specific domain.
Because when I add second domain it should only get file from folder assigned in virtual host for given subdomain

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I added question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that all of the hosts that you are browsing to have the same IP address. Perhaps this would help

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} !^api.system.com
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Haven't tested it on my own systems but it should return a 404 error when browsing to any URL other than api.system.com. Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: Or use an explicit [default vhost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#default) to catch all the other requests.